# Move semantics when calling a C++11 library from pre-C++11 code

Tags: c++, c++11, move-semantics

Say that you create a library with a class `MyClass` that has proper move assignment operators and move constructors. Furthermore, this library has properly defined and implemented `MyClass MyClass::operator + (const MyClass& other)`. This class is compiled with `-std=c++11` in order for these operators and syntax like `MyClass&&` to make sense.

If you later have a program **not** compiled with `-std=c++11` using this library and creating instances of the class `MyClass`, will you be able to take advantage of move semantics?

That, is will the following call the move constructor of `MyClass`?

```
MyClass first, second;
// initialize first and second
MyClass moved = first + second; // hopefully uses move semantics
```

I know that this code could not create its own class and use syntax like `MyClass&&` without having compilation errors, but hopefully it would still be able to take advantage of C++11 by using the C++11 library...

Thanks for any clarification.

Comment: I suspect you won't be able to compile your program since it won't recognize the C++11 syntax contained in the library headers.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The ABI of C++03 and C++11 doesn't differ, so object files aren't a problem. Your library can use C++11 internally as much as you want, but headers with C++11 syntax can't be used for C++03 projects, the compiler throws errors.

Comment: C++ doesn't specify an ABI and compilers can change the ABI whenever they feel like it.

Comment: I guess you mean in GCC?

Comment: They can do, but realistically, they can't do, at least on Linux. The breakage would be severe.

Comment: Well if your compiler is fully compliant they will most likely differ. One example is `std::list` that in C++11 become bigger by one `size_t`, and `std::string` with `libstdc++`. Those are not standard compliant in the libstdc++, unless you use the new abi (that is obviously not backward compatible). I posted a similar question (http://stackoverflow.com/questions/10014042/libary-compatibility-between-c11-and-c03), and the accepted answer is basically "no".

Answer (score 2):

The library's separately compiled internal implementation details may make use of move semantics. The header and the caller may make no use of move semantics, since they're not supported.